# Inserting php in a custom html module

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, custom-module

I'm trying to introduce a simple php in a custom html module and it doesn't let me do it.Why?

This is the code:

```
<p> </p>
< ? php 
   echo " Hello World" . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more than just a line of code...what/where is the file, what does "won't let me" mean?  An error code, no output, blank screen?

Comment: While editing the question, I notice that your PHP tag contains blanks - it should be `<?php` , not `< ? php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Joomla doesn't allow you to use PHP in the editor. You will need to download a 3rd party extension to allow this feature. I would strongly recommend [Sourcerer](https://nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer).

Once installed, simply wrap your code around `{source}` tags like so:

```
{source}
<?php
     echo " Hello World" . "\n";
?>
{/source}
```

Comment: I have tryed to install Sourcerer and it says it's not compatible :(. So what can I do?. Regards

Comment: @zoit - As of version 4.4.8, compatibility was removed for Joomla versions under 3.3.0, so please make sure you update your Joomla site to the latest version which is currently 3.3.6. There is no reason why you should ever be on an out of date version when using a STR. If for some reason you are unable to upgrade to Joomla 3.3.6, then you will need to download an older version of Sourcerer: https://nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#changelog

Comment: Yes it's the 3.3.6 right now

Comment: If that's the case, then  there should be no errors messages when trying to install Sourcerer.

Comment: It says: This extension is not compatible with PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15. Need PHP 5.3.13 or higher to install and use this extension.

Comment: Try installing this version: http://download.nonumber.nl/?ext=sourcerer&v=4.4.7

Comment: It would be the same with jQuery and JavaScript?.

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is add the `<script>` tags instead of `<?php` ;)

Comment: The new code is as I have right now, but it doesn't work, so I don't know why.

Comment: I rejected your edit. Please update your question with any code updates. My answer is there for a very simple demonstration ;)